# Printing multiple ArrayList objects in separate lines in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class containing some basic info about a course and an `ArrayList` containing objects of student class.
Is there a smarter way of editing the `toString()` method in order to print out information about the course and each student (on a separate line each) then this:

```
public String toString() {
    System.out.println("Course " + this.name + ", Teacher: " + this.teacher;
    for (Student stud: studentList) {
        System.out.println(stud);
    }
    retutn "";
```

I have already set the Student class' `toString()` method to print Student info.

*edit: Realised I made a mistake with `print(stud)`, so changet to `println(stud)`

Comment: `System.out.println(stud);` **println**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you want to print one student per line, use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print`
- You shouldn't *print* stuff in `toString`, you should just *return* a descriptive string.

In this case it looks like you wanted a method to print stuff, so use something else than `toString`. Perhaps `printCourseInfo` for instance:

```
public void printCourseInfo() {
    System.out.println("Course " + name + ", Teacher: " + teacher);
    for (Student stud: studentList) {
        System.out.println(stud);        // Note println instead of print
    }
}
```

---

**Bonus part:** If you're using Java 8, you could do

```
studentList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I assumed that printing in `toString` should be avoided. What's stopping me from actually defining a separate print method is the instruction I was given for this homework, which asks me to modify `toString` in order "to provide a printout of the course information first, followed by the information of all the students contained on the array".

Comment: You should then 1) use the toString as method name, 2) create a `String result` in the beginning of the method, and 3) change each printout to `result = result + <string to append>` and 4) end the method with `return result`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `System.out.println(stud)` in stead of `System.out.print(stud)`

What the "println" does, is printing each Student on a new line

Also see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for everything on System

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `toString()` method you should be returning a string, not printing it out.

Since you're using `System.out.print` in this case, that means you probably want to print stuff out. So change it to `System.out.println` in your for-each loop

```
public void printCourseInfo() { 
    System.out.println("Course " + name + ", Teacher: " + teacher);
    for (Student stud: studentList) {
        System.out.println(stud);    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned that you shouldn't really repurpose toString().
Instead you should implement a method like 'getAsPrettyString()' etc.
If you're lazy (like me) you might want to use something like this :

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;

public class Blah {
    private String hello;
    private List<String>helloList;

    public String getAsPrettyString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
    }   
}
```

[Using commons lang etc.](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-lang3%7C3.3.2%7Cjar)